# Rails Nginx Passenger Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, capistrano, bundler, passenger

I have a Rails 3.2.14 app that deploys and operates fine on a production server.  I'm working on deploying it to another server to test changes before I push out to production.  I'm running the latest version of passenger/nginx and using Capistrano 2.12.0 with Ruby 1.9.3-p194 due to this being a legacy app and I'm trying to mimic the environment.

I can deploy the app without a problem, but it won't spawn passenger and start up the app.

Here's one of the errors I get in /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
[ 2014-08-10 07:09:08.7782 733/7f2626fb2700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:284 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/d
eploy/exigencad/current: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: aa5360f9
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-0aEhJZ.html
  Message from application: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:263:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:366:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:261:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'


[ 2014-08-10 07:09:08.7874 733/7f2624c8d700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2305 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session
 because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is . Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
App 1521 stdout: 
App 1521 stdout:
```

I noticed an error about bundler but I did install the bundler gem, and here's my output running as deploy user or root user:

```
bundle -v
Bundler version 1.1.4
```

Here's the specific error log file for passenger

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="Phusion Passenger">
    <title>Web application could not be started</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
    font-family: Verdana, 'Bitstream Vera Sans', Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    background: white;
    color: #222222;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 3em;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    padding-left: 4.5em;
    padding-right: 4.5em;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 17pt;
    font-weight: medium;
    color: #533e72;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #533e72;
}

h1.title {
    margin-top: 0;
}

h1.error_title {
    color: red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

dt {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #280050;
}

dd {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.commands {
    border: 1px solid #b594e7;
    background: #ddc6ff;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    font-family: 'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Monospace;
}

pre {
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    text-align: left;
}

table.backtrace th {
    background: #8470a6;
    color: white;
}

table.backtrace th,
table.backtrace td {
    padding: 0.2em;
    padding-left: 0.4em;
    padding-right: 0.4em;
}

table.backtrace tr td {
    background: #ecdfff;
}

table.backtrace tr.even td {
    background: #f7f2ff;
}

table.backtrace td.index {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#site_footer {
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    font-size: small;
    color: #777777;
}

#site_footer a {
    color: #65498e;
}

#site_footer a:hover {
    color: #9681d9;
}

#site_header .corporate_identity {
    display: none;
}

    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.modrails.com/error_pages/1.0/error_page.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        dd {
            text-align: left;
        }

        dd pre {
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="site_container">
        <div id="site_header">
            <ul class="corporate_identity">
                <li class="logo"><a href="https://www.phusionpassenger.com"><span>Phusion Passenger</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="site_body">
            <h1 class="error_title">Web application could not be started</h1>
            <div id="content">
                <pre>cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:<wbr>36:<wbr>in `require&apos;
  /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:<wbr>36:<wbr>in `require&apos;
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:<wbr>263:<wbr>in `block in run_load_path_setup_code&apos;
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:<wbr>366:<wbr>in `running_bundler&apos;
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:<wbr>261:<wbr>in `run_load_path_setup_code&apos;
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:<wbr>100:<wbr>in `preload_app&apos;
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:<wbr>158:<wbr>in `&lt;module:<wbr>App&gt;&apos;
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:<wbr>29:<wbr>in `&lt;module:<wbr>PhusionPassenger&gt;&apos;
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:<wbr>28:<wbr>in `&lt;main&gt;&apos;
</pre>

                <dl>
                <dt>Error ID</dt>
                <dd>aa5360f9</dd>
                <dt>Application root</dt>
                <dd>/home/deploy/exigencad/current</dd>
                <dt>Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)</dt>
                <dd>production</dd>

                    <dt>Ruby interpreter command</dt>
                    <dd><pre>/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby</pre></dd>

                <dt>User and groups</dt>
                <dd><pre>uid=<wbr>1000(deploy) gid=<wbr>1000(deploy) groups=<wbr>1000(deploy),<wbr>27(sudo)
</pre></dd>
                <dt>Environment variables</dt>
                <dd><pre>RBENV_VERSION =<wbr> 1.9.3-p194
TERM =<wbr> xterm-256color
SHELL =<wbr> /bin/bash
PYTHONUNBUFFERED =<wbr> 1
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR =<wbr> /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXX3H8hx2
SERVER_PORT =<wbr> 80
USER =<wbr> deploy
DOCUMENT_ROOT =<wbr> /home/deploy/exigencad/current/public
SCGI =<wbr> 1
RBENV_ROOT =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv
REQUEST_URI =<wbr> /
IN_PASSENGER =<wbr> 1
RACK_ENV =<wbr> production
RBENV_HOOK_PATH =<wbr> :<wbr>/home/deploy/.rbenv/rbenv.d:<wbr>/usr/local/etc/rbenv.d:<wbr>/etc/rbenv.d:<wbr>/usr/lib/rbenv/hooks
REMOTE_PORT =<wbr> 64649
PATH =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin:<wbr>/home/deploy/.rbenv/libexec:<wbr>/home/deploy/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:<wbr>/usr/local/sbin:<wbr>/usr/local/bin:<wbr>/sbin:<wbr>/bin:<wbr>/usr/sbin:<wbr>/usr/bin
WSGI_ENV =<wbr> production
PWD =<wbr> /home/deploy/exigencad/current
LANG =<wbr> en_US.UTF-8
NODE_PATH =<wbr> /usr/share/passenger/node
NODE_ENV =<wbr> production
REMOTE_ADDR =<wbr> 75.89.97.25
SERVER_NAME =<wbr> prod.hcems.com
HOME =<wbr> /home/deploy
SHLVL =<wbr> 0
RAILS_ENV =<wbr> production
RBENV_DIR =<wbr> /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts
SERVER_SOFTWARE =<wbr> nginx/1.6.0
LOGNAME =<wbr> deploy
QUERY_STRING =<wbr> 
SERVER_ADDR =<wbr> 72.14.181.99
SERVER_PROTOCOL =<wbr> HTTP/1.1
PASSENGER_APP_ENV =<wbr> production
REQUEST_METHOD =<wbr> GET
</pre></dd>
                <dt>Ulimits</dt>
                <dd><pre>Unknown</pre></dd>

                    <dt>System metrics</dt>
                    <dd><pre>------------- General -------------
Kernel version    :<wbr> 3.15.4-x86_64-linode45
Uptime            :<wbr> 14h 3m 25s
Load averages     :<wbr> 0.01%,<wbr> 0.22%,<wbr> 0.27%
Fork rate         :<wbr> unknown

------------- CPU -------------
Number of CPUs    :<wbr>    4
Average CPU usage :<wbr>   0%  --   0% user,<wbr>   0% nice,<wbr>   0% system,<wbr> 100% idle
  CPU 1           :<wbr>   0%  --   0% user,<wbr>   0% nice,<wbr>   0% system,<wbr> 100% idle
  CPU 2           :<wbr>   0%  --   0% user,<wbr>   0% nice,<wbr>   0% system,<wbr> 100% idle
  CPU 3           :<wbr>   0%  --   0% user,<wbr>   0% nice,<wbr>   0% system,<wbr> 100% idle
  CPU 4           :<wbr>   0%  --   0% user,<wbr>   0% nice,<wbr>   0% system,<wbr> 100% idle
I/O pressure      :<wbr>   0%
  CPU 1           :<wbr>   0%
  CPU 2           :<wbr>   0%
  CPU 3           :<wbr>   0%
  CPU 4           :<wbr>   0%
Interference from other VMs:<wbr>   0%
  CPU 1                    :<wbr>   0%
  CPU 2                    :<wbr>   0%
  CPU 3                    :<wbr>   0%
  CPU 4                    :<wbr>   0%

------------- Memory -------------
RAM total         :<wbr>   4002 MB
RAM used          :<wbr>    205 MB (5%)
RAM free          :<wbr>   3797 MB
Swap total        :<wbr>    255 MB
Swap used         :<wbr>      0 MB (0%)
Swap free         :<wbr>    255 MB
Swap in           :<wbr> unknown
Swap out          :<wbr> unknown

</pre></dd>


                    <dt>General Ruby interpreter information</dt>
                    <dd><pre>RUBY_VERSION =<wbr> 1.9.3
RUBY_PLATFORM =<wbr> x86_64-linux
RUBY_ENGINE =<wbr> ruby
RubyGems version =<wbr> 1.8.23
RubyGems paths =<wbr> [&quot;/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1&quot;,<wbr> &quot;/home/deploy/.gem/ruby/1.9.1&quot;]
</pre></dd>


                    <dt>Ruby configuration (RbConfig::CONFIG)</dt>
                    <dd><pre>DESTDIR =<wbr> 
MAJOR =<wbr> 1
MINOR =<wbr> 9
TEENY =<wbr> 1
PATCHLEVEL =<wbr> 194
INSTALL =<wbr> /usr/bin/install -c
EXEEXT =<wbr> 
prefix =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194
ruby_install_name =<wbr> ruby
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME =<wbr> ruby
RUBY_SO_NAME =<wbr> ruby
exec =<wbr> exec
ruby_pc =<wbr> ruby-1.9.pc
PACKAGE =<wbr> ruby
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS =<wbr>  newline.c
USE_RUBYGEMS =<wbr> YES
MANTYPE =<wbr> doc
NROFF =<wbr> /usr/bin/nroff
vendorhdrdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/vendor_ruby
sitehdrdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/site_ruby
rubyhdrdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1
UNIVERSAL_INTS =<wbr> 
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES =<wbr> 
configure_args =<wbr>  &apos;--prefix=<wbr>/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194&apos; &apos;LDFLAGS=<wbr>-L/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib &apos; &apos;CPPFLAGS=<wbr>-I/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/include &apos;
vendordir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
sitedir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby
ruby_version =<wbr> 1.9.1
sitearch =<wbr> x86_64-linux
arch =<wbr> x86_64-linux
RI_BASE_NAME =<wbr> ri
ridir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/share/ri
rubylibprefix =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby
MAKEFILES =<wbr> Makefile
THREAD_MODEL =<wbr> pthread
SYMBOL_PREFIX =<wbr> 
EXPORT_PREFIX =<wbr> 
COMMON_HEADERS =<wbr> 
COMMON_MACROS =<wbr> 
COMMON_LIBS =<wbr> 
MAINLIBS =<wbr> 
ENABLE_SHARED =<wbr> no
DLDLIBS =<wbr>  -lc
SOLIBS =<wbr> 
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED =<wbr> -Wl,<wbr>-R -Wl,<wbr>/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib -L/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib 
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC =<wbr> -Wl,<wbr>-R -Wl,<wbr>/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib -L/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib -lruby-static
LIBRUBYARG =<wbr> -Wl,<wbr>-R -Wl,<wbr>/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib -L/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib -lruby-static
LIBRUBY =<wbr> libruby-static.a
LIBRUBY_ALIASES =<wbr> libruby.so
LIBRUBY_SO =<wbr> libruby.so.1.9.1
LIBRUBY_A =<wbr> libruby-static.a
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME =<wbr> 
rubyw_install_name =<wbr> 
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS =<wbr> 
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED =<wbr> gcc -shared
warnflags =<wbr> -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=<wbr>pointer-arith -Werror=<wbr>write-strings -Werror=<wbr>declaration-after-statement -Werror=<wbr>implicit-function-declaration
debugflags =<wbr> -ggdb
optflags =<wbr> -O3
cxxflags =<wbr>  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=<wbr>pointer-arith -Werror=<wbr>write-strings -Werror=<wbr>declaration-after-statement -Werror=<wbr>implicit-function-declaration
cflags =<wbr>  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=<wbr>pointer-arith -Werror=<wbr>write-strings -Werror=<wbr>declaration-after-statement -Werror=<wbr>implicit-function-declaration
cppflags =<wbr> -I/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/include 
NULLCMD =<wbr> :<wbr>
INSTALLDOC =<wbr> all
CAPITARGET =<wbr> nodoc
RDOCTARGET =<wbr> rdoc
EXECUTABLE_EXTS =<wbr> 
ARCHFILE =<wbr> 
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE =<wbr> no
EXTOUT =<wbr> .ext
PREP =<wbr> miniruby
TEST_RUNNABLE =<wbr> yes
setup =<wbr> Setup
EXTSTATIC =<wbr> 
STRIP =<wbr> strip -S -x
TRY_LINK =<wbr> 
LIBPATHENV =<wbr> LD_LIBRARY_PATH
RPATHFLAG =<wbr>  -Wl,<wbr>-R%1$-s
LIBPATHFLAG =<wbr>  -L%1$-s
LINK_SO =<wbr> 
LIBEXT =<wbr> a
DLEXT2 =<wbr> 
DLEXT =<wbr> so
LDSHAREDXX =<wbr> g++ -shared
LDSHARED =<wbr> gcc -shared
CCDLFLAGS =<wbr> -fPIC
STATIC =<wbr> 
ARCH_FLAG =<wbr> 
DLDFLAGS =<wbr> 
ALLOCA =<wbr> 
WERRORFLAG =<wbr> -Werror
CHDIR =<wbr> cd -P
RMALL =<wbr> rm -fr
RMDIRS =<wbr> rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p
RMDIR =<wbr> rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
CP =<wbr> cp
RM =<wbr> rm -f
PKG_CONFIG =<wbr> pkg-config
DOXYGEN =<wbr> 
DOT =<wbr> 
MAKEDIRS =<wbr> /bin/mkdir -p
MKDIR_P =<wbr> /bin/mkdir -p
INSTALL_DATA =<wbr> /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
INSTALL_SCRIPT =<wbr> /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_PROGRAM =<wbr> /usr/bin/install -c
SET_MAKE =<wbr> 
LN_S =<wbr> ln -s
NM =<wbr> nm
DLLWRAP =<wbr> 
WINDRES =<wbr> 
OBJCOPY =<wbr> objcopy
OBJDUMP =<wbr> objdump
ASFLAGS =<wbr> 
AS =<wbr> as
AR =<wbr> ar
RANLIB =<wbr> ranlib
try_header =<wbr> 
COUTFLAG =<wbr> -o 
OUTFLAG =<wbr> -o 
CPPOUTFILE =<wbr> -o conftest.i
GNU_LD =<wbr> yes
GCC =<wbr> yes
EGREP =<wbr> /bin/grep -E
GREP =<wbr> /bin/grep
CPP =<wbr> gcc -E
CXXFLAGS =<wbr>  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=<wbr>pointer-arith -Werror=<wbr>write-strings -Werror=<wbr>declaration-after-statement -Werror=<wbr>implicit-function-declaration
CXX =<wbr> g++
OBJEXT =<wbr> o
CPPFLAGS =<wbr> -I/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/include   -I/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/include 
LDFLAGS =<wbr> -L. -L/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib  -rdynamic -Wl,<wbr>-export-dynamic
CFLAGS =<wbr>  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=<wbr>pointer-arith -Werror=<wbr>write-strings -Werror=<wbr>declaration-after-statement -Werror=<wbr>implicit-function-declaration
CC =<wbr> gcc
target_os =<wbr> linux
target_vendor =<wbr> unknown
target_cpu =<wbr> x86_64
target =<wbr> x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
host_os =<wbr> linux-gnu
host_vendor =<wbr> unknown
host_cpu =<wbr> x86_64
host =<wbr> x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
RUBYW_BASE_NAME =<wbr> rubyw
RUBY_BASE_NAME =<wbr> ruby
build_os =<wbr> linux-gnu
build_vendor =<wbr> unknown
build_cpu =<wbr> x86_64
build =<wbr> x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE =<wbr> 2012-04-20
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION =<wbr> 1.9.3
BASERUBY =<wbr> echo executable host ruby is required.  use --with-baseruby option.;<wbr> false
target_alias =<wbr> 
host_alias =<wbr> 
build_alias =<wbr> 
LIBS =<wbr> -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm 
ECHO_T =<wbr> 
ECHO_N =<wbr> -n
ECHO_C =<wbr> 
DEFS =<wbr> 
mandir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/share/man
localedir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/share/locale
libdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib
psdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/share/doc/ruby
pdfdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/share/doc/ruby
dvidir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/share/doc/ruby
htmldir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/share/doc/ruby
infodir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/share/info
docdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/share/doc/ruby
oldincludedir =<wbr> /usr/include
includedir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/include
localstatedir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/var
sharedstatedir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/com
sysconfdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/etc
datadir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/share
datarootdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/share
libexecdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/libexec
sbindir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/sbin
bindir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin
exec_prefix =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194
PACKAGE_URL =<wbr> 
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT =<wbr> 
PACKAGE_STRING =<wbr> 
PACKAGE_VERSION =<wbr> 
PACKAGE_TARNAME =<wbr> 
PACKAGE_NAME =<wbr> 
PATH_SEPARATOR =<wbr> :<wbr>
SHELL =<wbr> /bin/bash
rubylibdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1
archdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
sitelibdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
sitearchdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
vendorlibdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
vendorarchdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
topdir =<wbr> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
</pre></dd>



                    <dt>Ruby load path ($LOAD_PATH)</dt>
                    <dd><pre>/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
</pre></dd>


                    <dt>Ruby loaded libraries ($LOADED_FEATURES)</dt>
                    <dd><pre>enumerator.so
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/etc.so
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/platform.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/path_support.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info/binary_compatibility.rb
/home/deploy/.passenger/native_support/4.0.48/ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-linux/passenger_native_support.so
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/socket.so
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/socket.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/thread.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_enhancements.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpdir.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/constants.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/public_api.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/debug_logging.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/shellwords.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/shellwords.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/message_client.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/native_support_utils.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/tee_input.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/union_station/connection.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/union_station/transaction.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/lock.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/union_station/core.rb
</pre></dd>

                </dl>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="site_footer">
            <!--
               You are free to modify the footer as you see fit,
               but we kindly ask of you to preserve to following
               text. Thank you.
            -->
            <div class="container">
                Powered by <a href="https://www.phusionpassenger.com/">Phusion Passenger</a>,
                <tt>mod_rails</tt> / <tt>mod_rack</tt> for Apache and Nginx.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's my capistrano deploy.rb in case it helps (note, working on production server, but when I change the IP to the staging server it deploys but doesn't run rake tasks or whenever gem to set crontab):

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "whenever/capistrano"

server "72.14.181.01", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "appname"
set :user, "deploy"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{application}"
#set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false
set :rails_env, "production"


set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:appguy/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"


default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases
after "deploy:update", "gps_listener:restart"

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
  desc "reload the database with seed data"
  task :seed do
    run "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
end

namespace :gps_listener do
  task :start do
    run "#{sudo} start app-gps"
  end

  task :stop do
    run "#{sudo} stop app-gps"
  end

  task :restart do
    run "#{sudo} stop app-gps && sleep 1 && #{sudo} start app-gps"
  end
end

task :after_update_code do
  run "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake gps:listen"
end
```

I'll admit, it's been a long time (1-2 years) since I've had to bootstrap a new server so recreating this legacy app with new versions of passenger/nginx is proving troublesome.  I'm not sure if it's an issue with passenger itself or if it's a ruby issue.

Here's my passenger config for nginx btw:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
   passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
   passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

Here's my default virtual host for /etc/nginx/site-available/default

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        server_name prod.hcems.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    production;
        root         /home/deploy/exigencad/current/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the problem was with my .bashrc file.

I had the following at the bottom of the file:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
```

Which was not setting my rbenv environment variable.  Once I moved it to the top of .bashrc I could deploy without an error. And passenger now spins up the application.

My whenever gem doesn't seem to be working (setting my crontab for rake tasks), but I'll open another question regarding that.

Comment: How come it wasn't seeing your rbenv environment variable? Does your bashrc call exit before reaching that line?

Comment: Good question.  I think .bashrc does exit before that line so moving that bit to the top seems to have fixed the problem with Passenger seeing the rbenv path.  After some research, I've read others having to do the same thing since Passenger is spawned via Bash.